# Smooth scrolling when on a subpage (WP/Bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap JS Scrollspy on my Wordpress site.

Scrollspy is working just fine on a landing page.

What I need is a smooth scrolling working on a subpage too, so it scrolls me to a part of the website which is located only on a landing page.

I've got a good experience with a slash before hashtag: `<a href"/#home"`> but it doesn't seem to work for me this case.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Add scrollspy to <body>
  $('body').scrollspy({target: ".navbar", offset: 50});   

  // Add smooth scrolling on all links inside the navbar
  $(".navbar a").on('click', function(event) {
    // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
    if (this.hash !== "") {
      // Prevent default anchor click behavior
      event.preventDefault();

      // Store hash
      var hash = this.hash;

      // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
      // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
      }, 800, function(){

        // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
        window.location.hash = hash;
      });
    }  // End if
  });
});
</script>
```